# Fix Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error

Tags: windows, multi-boot, grub, linux-mint, bootloader

So i wanted to try linus mint.so i installed it my laptop..so i already had windows so i created a differnt partition on a different drive and installed it there.later i switch to windows and saw that one drive is empty and linus is with the drive that i used to store games etc...so what i did is i tried to merge those so what left was 2 drive c and d...... c is windows and d is linus and my games data etc..so now when i tried to switch on my lap..its showing this error..i tired few diffrent methords like ls and finding where i installed linus but its not showing any file format ext??

So what should i do? I cant even load windows or even bios or boot menu..

Please help

Comment: If all you wanted to do was try it, then you should have installed it within a vm.